# How to limit the number of characters printed in each line in java?

Tags: java

I am working on a program in java for practice, and I have almost everything completed except for one part of the program.

Let me give a quick background on the program before I dive right into my question. Basically, the program reads in data from a .txt file, stored the information in a HashMap, and then prints the output in a desire format to another txt file.

Each line that is printed out needs to have a maximum character length of 330. If it get close to reaching that limit, it basically needs to go to the next line and continue printing where it left off.

I have uploaded a link to my dropbox files (link is here: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/n5pw928i3xbw3an/AABc0lAv1FU4bDXtva3DbNG0a?dl=0) which contains an example input file (the file that will actually be read into my program), a file which is an example of how the information should be correctly printed, and then a file that shows what the current output looks like with my unfinished program.

Also, below is all my code for this program... it's not very long. If anyone can give some advice on how to solve this problem, I'd be greatly appreciative. Let me know if I can provide anything else.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.Files;



public class Processor {

private String[] finalArray;
private int numberOfCpt;
private int quantity;
private int i = 1;
private int length;
private int length1;
private int lineLength;
private HashMap<Integer, LinkedList<String>> map = new HashMap<Integer, 
                   LinkedList<String>>();
private String[] columns;



public Processor() {
  finalArray = new String[0];
}


public void readFile(String fileIn) throws IOException {

  String fileName = fileIn;

  Files.lines(Paths.get(fileName)).forEach(
        s -> {
           columns = s.split("\t");
           Integer key = Integer.parseInt(columns[0]);
           if (!map.containsKey(key)) {
              map.put(key, new LinkedList<String>());
           }
           map.get(key).add(columns[1]);
        });

}


public String generateReport() {

  String output = "";
  String line1 = "";
  String output1 = "";

  for (int c = 0; c < 15000; c++) {
     if (map.get(c) == null) {
        System.out.print("");
     }

     else {
        for (int z = 0; z < 1; z++) {
           output1 += "If ";

           output1 += "IsCPT" + "(\"" 
                      + map.get(c).toString().replace(" ", "") 
                      + "\"" + ")";

           output1 += " Then\n   If Quantity > " + c + 
                      " AND Allowance   >" 
                      + " 0.0 Then \n      HoldBill(\"MUE Edits\")"
                      + "\n   End If\n";
           if (c >= 1) {
              output1 += "Else";
           }               

           if (output1.contains("[")) {
              output1 = output1.replace("[", ""); 
           }

           if (output1.contains("]")) {
              output1 = output1.replace("]", "");
           }
           output = output1;
        }
     }
  }
  return output;
}



private static ArrayList<String> charLimiter(String input, int limit) {
  ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
  String[] parts = input.split(",");
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  for (String part : parts) {
     if (sb.length() + part.length() > limit) {
        list.add(sb.toString().substring(0, sb.toString().length()));
        sb = new StringBuilder();
     }
     sb.append(part + ",");
  }

  if (sb.length() > 0) {
     list.add(sb.toString());
  }

  return list;
}
}
```

Comment: You would need to print one word at a time.  Before printing, check if the number of characters remaining is greater than 1+numCharInWord (the 1 is for the leading space).  If not, insert a newline.

Comment: I'm not really following... In my generateReport() method, I am basically looping though every number from 1 to 15000 and printing any values that are contained in each number (for instance, when my loop starts at map.get[1].toString(), that is going to print every code that has a value of 1 (which is around 7700 codes). How would I print that 1 word at a time?

Comment: You want to limit the length of lines, you need to determine if the current chunk to be printed is shorter than the remaining line length (that's a variable!) and if not, add a newline (and reset the variable).

Comment: man, I hate to be that guy, but I'm struggling to understand the logic.

"determine if the current chunk to be printed is shorter than the remaining line length" - How to I decide what the "current chunk to be printed is", since the "chunk" will be 7700 CPT codes

how do i declare a variable to return the length of the "remaining" line length?

Comment: Well, at first glance at your code, I see this `for (int z = 0; z < 1; z++)`.  So, right away that looks suspicious, as you will execute this loop exactly once.

Comment: indeed... Draco corrected me on that. I'm not sure what that output was corrected even with that particle loop.

edit: I'm still trying to figure out how to get the character limits to work with out messing up a ton of what i already have. The hints above helped, but haven't fully click yet.

Comment: If you've already made a code correction, please reflect that in what you have posted.

Comment: Also, there are some coding style issues.  If `map.get(c) == null` you write zero bytes to the output stream.  Why bother?  Did you mean `println("")` which would give you a newline char to the output stream?  If `map.get(c)` is not `null` then you execute the else statement which is the rest of the 'generateReport()' method.  Just do a `return` after the `System.out.print()` and then you don't need the `else` clause and its accompanying increase in code block nesting.  The simpler your code is, the easier it is to debug.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I'll keep those in mind and am making the changes now.

... still banging my head against the wall trying to figure out the character limit for the output

Comment: I have this feeling you're not stepping through the code with a debugger examining variables as you go.  What development environment are you using?

Comment: jGrasp - it's provided by my university and has a debugger, which I'm using.

how would a debugger help me figure out how to make a character limit for each line and get an output like in the example files i posted?

Comment: Well you've written this code, so you expect it to work a specific way.  Stepping through the code, line by line and examining the contents of variable will illuminate where your coding mistakes are.  For example, if you had debugged your `for` loop, you'd have seen that when `z` was incremented from 0 to 1, the loop exited.  That's your "Aha!" moment.